# C# component events?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, unmanaged

I am attempting to write a C# component which will expose events. The component is to be imported by an unmanaged C++ application. According to a few tutorials I have come up with this code (for the C# side):

```
namespace COMTest
{
[ComVisible(true),
Guid("02271CDF-BDB9-4cfe-B65B-2FA58FF1F64B"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ITestEvents
{
    void OnTest();
}

[ComVisible(true),
Guid("87BA4D3A-868E-4233-A324-30035154F8A4")]
public interface ITest
{
    void RaiseTest();
} // End of ITest

[ComVisible(true),
Guid("410CD174-8933-4f8c-A799-8EE82AF4A9F2"),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ITestEvents))]
public class TestImplimentation : ITest
{
    public TestImplimentation()
    {
    }

    public void RaiseTest()
    {
        if (null != OnTest)
            OnTest();
    }

    public delegate void Test (); //No need to expose this delegate
    public event Test OnTest;
}
}
```

Now my c++ code has a simple:

```
#import "COMTest.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
```

Which generates a tlh file. This tlh file contains everything but my event (OnTest). What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM Event Sinks are pretty evil to the uninitiated.

The steps basically are

- create an outgoing (source) interface
- Implement an
  IConnectionPointContainer and
  IConnectionPoint Interfaces, use
  these to pass a client implementation
  of the source Interface

The **good** news is that in the interop namespace there are attributes to help you do this (mostly) automatically ([ComSourceInterfacesAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comsourceinterfacesattribute.aspx)) There is a decent example of its usage [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I'm doing in my example, thats not working.

Comment: I have this working. I didnt realize that the tlh file would only generate information for the classes I was using. As soon as I made my c++ class inherit from the ITestEvents class, everything started working properly. Thanks for the information.